# Android: Eclipse gdb error when debugging native code

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, gdb

I followed a couple of tutorials on line, trying to setup gdb to debug native code:

1. Chapter 11 of the book Android NDK Beginners Guide.
2. Video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hMV7Xqcn39k&list=PLD89B891EF9D26F14&feature=mh_lolz
3. Forum: http://wiki.eclipse.org/Sequoyah/ndk_guide

None of them got my debugger working completely.

I now have a specific problem by following steps, which are agreed by all the above tutorials as the correct steps to debug native code:

1. In Eclipse, Start my JAVA debugging session and stops at the first breakpoint in my onCreate() method.
2. In terminal, under my project folder, run ndk-build-eclipse (the copy of the original ndk-gdb without the last line about auto-connecting gdb client to server), with no obvious warning or errors.
3. In terminal, chmod +x MY_PROJECT/obj/local/armeabi/app_process (I'm on a mac), otherwise I'll get "Cannot run MY_PROJECT/obj/local/armeabi/app_process, for unknown reason" error. This app_process is set as GDB debugger in my C++ debug configuration.
4. In Eclipse, start my C++ debug configuration.

Then I got an error dialog say:

```
Error creating session
 Process Terminated
    Process Terminated
    Process Terminated
```

Comment: I solved the problem myself. Thanks. Please vote me up if you had the same trouble.

Answer (score 0):

(Solved by the OP in a question edit. Converted to a community wiki answer. See [Question with no answers, but issue solved in the comments (or extended in chat)](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251597/question-with-no-answers-but-issue-solved-in-the-comments) )

The OP wrote:

> Solved this myself:
>
> I put the wrong gdb debugger in my C++ debug configuration (under Debugger tab).
>
> - The one should've been in there (NDK r7b):
>     `$NDKROOT/toolchains/$ARCH/prebuilt//bin/arm-linux-androideabi-gdb`
> - The one I wrongly put in there:
>     `${PROJECT_DIR}/obj/local/armeabi/app_process`, which should be only
>     put in the C/C++ Application under Main tab.
>
> Fixing this solved my problem, and now I can debug native code using gdb in Eclipse!!